# How to get object parameter from li element that have append

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, object, parameters

I have simple 'data' include li tag and data.
then I have append it to 'ul' tag.
I want each li tag can click to pass its some data to txtBox.

I use 'for loop' to make string value to append like..

```
datata = '<li onclick = "getset('+ data[i] +')></li>">';
```

In function getset I expect click to sent for 1 object like...

```
{
   id: 1,
   name: "namename1",
   lname: "imlname1",
   job: "artist",
   ages: "17"
}
```

Then. can use value in object like... getData.name, getData.job,...

```
function getset(getData){
 getData.name = document.getElementById("txtBox").value;
}
```

but.. all I get just error **'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier'**

**Why that happend?? thank you**

```js
window.onload = function () {
            data = [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    name: "namename1",
                    lname: "imlname1",
                    job: "artist",
                    ages: "17"
                }, {
                    id: 2,
                    name: "namename2",
                    lname: "imlname2",
                    job: "artist",
                    ages: "25"
                }, {
                    id: 3,
                    name: "namename3",
                    lname: "imlname3",
                    job: "artist",
                    ages: "15"
                }, {
                    id: 4,
                    name: "namename4",
                    lname: "imlname4",
                    job: "artist",
                    ages: "18"
                }, {
                    id: 5,
                    name: "namename5",
                    lname: "imlname5",
                    job: "artist",
                    ages: "27"
                }
            ];
            var datata = '';
            for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                datata += '<li onclick="getset(' + data[i] + '  )">' + data[i].name + '</li>';
            }
     
            $("ul").append(datata);
        }

        function getset(data) {
            console.log("1");
            console.log(data);
        }
```

```css
li {
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
            margin-top: -1px;
            /* Prevent double borders */
            background-color: #f6f6f6;
            padding: 12px;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size: 18px;
            color: black;
            display: block;
            /* Make it into a block element to fill the whole list */
            position: relative;
}

li:hover {
            background-color: #adadad;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>TEST</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
   
</head>

<body>
    

    <input type="search" id="txtBox">
    <ul id="ulTag">

    </ul>

</body>

</html>
```

last of result I will make textbox to search data from 'data',variable, then click to get textbox complete data.

Comment: *"In function getset I **expect** click to sent for 1 object"* - well, there's your problem.

Comment: Hi @savecost please use data[i].id instead of data[i] where you creating the dynamic li. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is because you're attempting to append an object to a string, and hence the type is coerced and, in this case, the data you need is lost.

A workaround would be to create an array of jQuery objects which you want to append, with each one having its relevant object stored in a `data` attribute on the element, which can easily be accessed from a delegated event handler something like this:

```
var datata = data.map(function(o) {
  return $('<li />', { text: o.name }).data('object', o);
}); 

$("ul").append(datata).on('click', 'li', function() {
  console.log($(this).data('object'));
});
```

```js
$(function() {
  var data = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "namename1",
    lname: "imlname1",
    job: "artist",
    ages: "17"
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: "namename2",
    lname: "imlname2",
    job: "artist",
    ages: "25"
  }, {
    id: 3,
    name: "namename3",
    lname: "imlname3",
    job: "artist",
    ages: "15"
  }];

  var datata = data.map(function(o) {
    return $('<li />', { text: o.name }).data('object', o);
  }); 
  
  $("ul").append(datata).on('click', 'li', function() {
    console.log($(this).data('object'));
  });  
});
```

```css
li {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-top: -1px;
  /* Prevent double borders */
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  display: block;
  /* Make it into a block element to fill the whole list */
  position: relative;
}

li:hover {
  background-color: #adadad;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="search" id="txtBox">
<ul id="ulTag"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use template literals and you need to use `JSON.stringify` to pass the object as parameter.

```
datata += `<li onclick=getset(${JSON.stringify(data[i])})>${data[i].name}</li>`;
```

```js
window.onload = function () {
            data = [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    name: "namename1",
                    lname: "imlname1",
                    job: "artist",
                    ages: "17"
                }, {
                    id: 2,
                    name: "namename2",
                    lname: "imlname2",
                    job: "artist",
                    ages: "25"
                }, {
                    id: 3,
                    name: "namename3",
                    lname: "imlname3",
                    job: "artist",
                    ages: "15"
                }, {
                    id: 4,
                    name: "namename4",
                    lname: "imlname4",
                    job: "artist",
                    ages: "18"
                }, {
                    id: 5,
                    name: "namename5",
                    lname: "imlname5",
                    job: "artist",
                    ages: "27"
                }
            ];
            var datata = '';
            for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                datata += `
                  <li onclick=getset(${JSON.stringify(data[i])})> ${data[i].name}</li>
                `;
            }
     
            $("ul").append(datata);
        }

        function getset(data) {
            console.log("1");
            console.log(data);
        }
```

```css
li {
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
            margin-top: -1px;
            /* Prevent double borders */
            background-color: #f6f6f6;
            padding: 12px;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size: 18px;
            color: black;
            display: block;
            /* Make it into a block element to fill the whole list */
            position: relative;
}

li:hover {
            background-color: #adadad;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>TEST</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
   
</head>

<body>
    

    <input type="search" id="txtBox">
    <ul id="ulTag">

    </ul>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: this is such a bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

thank you all for answers and thank Rory . I get idea from you.

that I understand.. if use

```
datata = '<li onclick = "getset('+ data[i] +')></li>">';
```

result is

```
<li onclick = "getset({id: 1,name: "namename1",lname: "imlname1",job: "artist",ages: "17"})></li>">';
```

then I try to use..

```
datata = '<li onclick="getset(data[' + i + '])">' + data[i].name + '</li>';
```

command is..

```
getset(data[0]);
```

not...

```
getset({id: 1,name: "namename1",lname: "imlname1",job: "artist",ages: "17"});
```

It's work also but I'm still not sure it's the right way.

Answer (score 0):

Rory covered the reason why your code doesn't work, and a workaround with jQuery. Here's another workaround with vanilla JS that

1) Attaches each object property as a data attribute to each list item

2) Adds a single event listener to the `<ul>` component instead of one per list item to listen to events from its children as they  bubble up the DOM ([event delegation](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate)).

```js
const data = [{"id":1,"name":"namename1","lname":"imlname1","job":"artist","ages":"17"},{"id":2,"name":"namename2","lname":"imlname2","job":"artist","ages":"25"},{"id":3,"name":"namename3","lname":"imlname3","job":"artist","ages":"15"},{"id":4,"name":"namename4","lname":"imlname4","job":"artist","ages":"18"},{"id":5,"name":"namename5","lname":"imlname5","job":"artist","ages":"27"}];

function handleClick(e) {

  // Destructure the dataset from the event target
  const { target: { dataset: { name, job, ages } } } = e;
  console.log(name, job, ages);
}

// `map`over the data and create an array of list items
const lis = data.map(obj => {
  return (
    `<li
      data-name="${obj.name}"
      data-job="${obj.job}"
      data-ages="${obj.ages}"
     >${obj.name}</li>`
  );
});

// Grab the `ul` element, add the list items to it, and add
// an event listener to listen for click events
const ul = document.querySelector('#ulTag');
ul.innerHTML = lis.join('');
ul.addEventListener('click', handleClick, false);
```

```html
<ul id="ulTag"></ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
datata = '<li onclick = "getset('+ data[i] +')></li>">';
```

should be:

```
datata = '<li onclick = "getset('+ data[i] +')"></li>';
```

Comment: Correct, but that won't fix OPs problem.

Comment: @freedomn-m actually it does. Just see the big picture.

Answer (score -2):

You are passign as a parameter an object. Html does not support having as params objects. I fixed your code:

You need to pass `data[i].id` not  `data[i]`.

```
 for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        datata += '<li onclick="getset(' + data[i].id + '  )">' + data[i].name + '</li>';
    }
```

And then retrieve by the id the item form the collection:

```
 function getset(id) {
                        const match =  data.find(e => e.id === id);
                        console.log('Selection: ', match);
                    }
```

```js
window.onload = function () {
            data = [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    name: "namename1",
                    lname: "imlname1",
                    job: "artist",
                    ages: "17"
                }, {
                    id: 2,
                    name: "namename2",
                    lname: "imlname2",
                    job: "artist",
                    ages: "25"
                }, {
                    id: 3,
                    name: "namename3",
                    lname: "imlname3",
                    job: "artist",
                    ages: "15"
                }, {
                    id: 4,
                    name: "namename4",
                    lname: "imlname4",
                    job: "artist",
                    ages: "18"
                }, {
                    id: 5,
                    name: "namename5",
                    lname: "imlname5",
                    job: "artist",
                    ages: "27"
                }
            ];
            var datata = '';
            for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                datata += '<li onclick="getset(' + data[i].id + '  )">' + data[i].name + '</li>';
            }
     
            $("ul").append(datata);
        }

        function getset(id) {
            const match =  data.find(e => e.id === id);
            console.log('Selection: ', match);
        }
```

```css
li {
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
            margin-top: -1px;
            /* Prevent double borders */
            background-color: #f6f6f6;
            padding: 12px;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size: 18px;
            color: black;
            display: block;
            /* Make it into a block element to fill the whole list */
            position: relative;
}

li:hover {
            background-color: #adadad;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>TEST</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
   
</head>

<body>
    

    <input type="search" id="txtBox">
    <ul id="ulTag">

    </ul>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @savecost completed the example